# Finding the index of similar columns in 2 numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2d numpy arrays of size `(12550,200)` and `(12550,10)`. I need to find the set of column indexes of the first array that are matching the 2nd array columns.

Eg:

```
ar1 = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[1,3,4,5],[6,7,8,5]]
ar2 = [[1,3],[4,6],[1,4],[6,8]]
```

so matching columns are `1,4,1,4` and `3,6,4,8`

I need the index of these columns in ar1 as output i.e., [0,2]

Can anyone help me with the python code that is fast enough as the original array dimensions are big

Comment: What if there are duplicates in the two arrays?

Comment: please show your effort

Comment: No, it won't contain duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
ar1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[1,3,4,5],[6,7,8,5]])
ar2 = np.array([[1,3],[4,6],[1,4],[6,8]])

np.where((ar1[:,None].T == ar2.T).all(axis=2))[0]
```

gives

```
array([0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

meaning column 0 of ar2 is found at column 0 of ar1, and column 1 of ar2 is found at column 2 of ar1.

The transpose is used because you care about columns rather than rows. The `[:,None]` is used for broadcasting (i.e. test every column against every other). The `all()` checks that entire columns match. And finally the `[0]` element of the `np.where` result will give you the ar1 column indices where this happens.